# Using Redis in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, redis, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

Is it possible to use Redis in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Based on what they have said online it is not recommended to use Redis in any Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [install Redis on Windows](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads), but for best use, I recommend you install to Linux on Docker.